# Loading Different jQuery Version and .js files for <IE8 and modern browsers

Tags: javascript, jsp, internet-explorer-8, liferay-6

This is a very particular situation. Im working on a web app that needs support for IE8 and above + modern browsers. For IE8 we have managed to load jquery 1.X plus JQUery UI (both of them in just one file) and we have JQuery 2 and JQuery UI for modern browsers (in another file). The thing is i need to find a way to load the Jquery 1.X plugins just for **IE8** and the rest of the plugins for modern browsers.

I have find some solutions when you have to add css targeting specific browsers but not something that would allow me to do something like this on a **jsp file**:

```
**Load just for modern browsers (ie9, ie10,ie11, chrome, firefox)** {
            <script type="text/javascript" src="/eacat-theme/js/jquery.autocomplete.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="/eacat-theme/js/ui.dropdownchecklist.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="/eacat-theme/js/noty/jquery.noty.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="/eacat-theme/js/noty/layouts/topCenter.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="/eacat-theme/js/noty/themes/default.js"></script>
```

}

```
**load just for ie8** {
            <script type="text/javascript" src="/eacat-theme/js/js-old/noty/jquery.noty.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="/eacat-theme/js/js-old/noty/layouts/topCenter.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="/eacat-theme/js/js-old/noty/themes/default.js"></script>
```

}

I have another problem, i can't use javascript as a solution to target specific browsers since the jquery version will have to load also depending on the browser. Any help will be really appreciated. I don't know if its usefull but since im working in **Liferay 6.2** i already have a class on the html tag that changes depending on the browser.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new theme (or edit a custom theme you created) and add the following lines inside the  tag:

```
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="$javascript_folder/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="$javascript_folder/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <!--[if gte IE 8]>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="$javascript_folder/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <!--[if !IE]>
        <!--><script type="text/javascript" src="$javascript_folder/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script><!-->
    <![endif]-->
```

i'm using this solution and it's working